# Add same field in Yii2 using ActiveForm

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, active-form

I'm new in Yii2. When I create a _form.php and I want add more fields of exist field.
My code in _form.php file:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\modules\admin\models\ProjectAssignment */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="project-assignment-form" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'project_id')->dropDownList(
        \app\modules\admin\models\Project::find()->select(['project_name', 'id'])->indexBy('id')->column(),
        ['prompt' => 'Select Project']
    )->label('Project') ?>

    <div class="MemberAssignment">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList(
            \app\modules\admin\models\User::find()->select(['username', 'id'])->indexBy('id')->column(),
            ['prompt' => 'Select User']
        )->label('Username') ?>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x plusform"></i>

    <!--
    <? /*= $form->field($model, 'active')->textInput() */ ?>

    <? /*= $form->field($model, 'created_date')->textInput() */ ?>

    -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

I want when click a button `<i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x plusform"></i>`, field of User will appeared more. Can I using AJAX for this?

Comment: You use this extension for add more same field https://github.com/GAMITG/yii2-dynamicform

Comment: It's not an option that I want.

Comment: To clarify, you want the `plusform` Button to do the following: Create an dropdown for Project selection and User selection, so you can submit more than one Project/User assignment in one go?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want. But I don't have solutions about this